# SQL Server : syntax wrong into stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple query like:

```
SELECT
    1 AS [Result],
    'success' AS [ResultText]

IF (@TaskStatusName = 'COMPLETED')
    SELECT 
        5 AS [ToNotifiedResult],
        SELECT @TechniciansEmail = COALESCE(@TechniciansEmail + ';', '') + [Username]  
        FROM Employee  AS [E]
  INNER JOIN TaskNotification AS [TN] ON TN.EmpKey = E.EmpKey AND TaskId = '64BB7072-62A5-4C8E-A385-3B3DCB8BD1CA' AS [ToNotified]
```

Problem is in the last select it just say

> Incorrect syntax near 'Select'

And "Select" word is marked in red

I try to group that select with parenthesis as:

```
 ,(SELECT @TechniciansEmail = COALESCE(@TechniciansEmail + ';', '') + [Username]  FROM Employee  AS [E]
  INNER JOIN TaskNotification AS [TN] ON TN.EmpKey = E.EmpKey AND TaskId = '64BB7072-62A5-4C8E-A385-3B3DCB8BD1CA' AS [ToNotified])
```

But now @`TechniciansEmail` variable is marked in red and I get

> Incorrect syntax near @TechniciansEmail. Expecting '(', or SELECT

I really don't know what am I doing wrong, any ideas?

Comment: I think you just need to remove the `Select` after the `,`.  But it's very confusing what you are trying to do. Also, the `AS [ToNotified]` shouldn't be part of the `JOIN` statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very hard to understand because it doesn't include enough detail for us to help you. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The first problem is the `SELECT`behind the field [ToNotifiedResult]. The second problem arises when you remove that `SELECT`: In a `SELECT` statement, you can only either return values or assign values to variables but not both.

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Describe what you are trying to do.  Don't just dump a broken query, and expect we magically understand what you are trying to do.  Sample input??? Expected output???  Table structure???

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
SELECT @TechniciansEmail = COALESCE(@TechniciansEmail + ';', '') + [Username]
```

is either completely out of place, or it's an attempt to create a subquery, in which case it needs to be in parenthesis, and to have its own FROM clause.

Actually, based on the second half of your question, it looks like you should just have this line as its own separate query, since it populates a variable:

```
SELECT  
    @TechniciansEmail = COALESCE(@TechniciansEmail + ';', '') + [Username]  
FROM 
    Employee  AS [E]
INNER JOIN 
    TaskNotification AS [TN] ON TN.EmpKey = E.EmpKey AND TaskId = '64BB7072-62A5-4C8E-A385-3B3DCB8BD1CA'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must give begin end on condition if on stored procedured. 
Like this 
If @sastro =`value`
Begin
Select * from where parameter=''
End
Else
Begin

Select .......
End